# How can I reuse DCM4CHEE code to send patient data to an equipment?

Tags: java, dcm4che

I use DCM4Chee to receive the DICOM from the equipments. All fine, DCM4Chee is a great software.

I now would like to send the patient data in advance to the equipment, so that the patient data is prefilled when the doctor or technician starts the examination.

I am not sure of how it works.

Should I send a kind of DICOM message with no image data to the equipment? Using dcmsnd utility, or something else?

I use the pacsdb database, and am able to create patient data. I think I will be able to create study data to be sent to the equipment, but how should I send this information to the equipment.

Ideas and examples are welcome :D.

Answer conclusion:
The way to go i sing the Modality Worklist from DCM4CHEE, populating it  using HL7 messages.

Interesting links:

- [DICOM Modality Worklist](http://dicomiseasy.blogspot.com/2012/04/dicom-modality-worklist.html)
- [Java HL7 opensource API](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/)
- [DCM4CHEE Modality Worklist](http://www.dcm4che.org/confluence/display/ee2/Modality+Worklist+SCP)
- [HL7 message format](https://www.hl7.org/documentcenter/public_temp_F5D6CEB0-1C23-BA17-0C0EF6C82DD3E177/wg/conf/HL7MSH.htm)

Comment: I believe that you would want to use a "modality worklist" to achieve this functionality, but I have no idea if DCM4Chee has an implementation of one for you.

Comment: @Chris O: Thanks for the tip. Investigating MWL (Modality Worklist)...

Comment: This question would make an excellent addition to the proposed [Healthcare IT](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65896/healthcare-it?referrer=zzSEh1b0idFc27gzFOBXTQ2) site (if it makes it out of Area 51 (thanks to your follow up vote))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to expand a bit on the topic.

The feature You are looking for is indeed Modality Worklist or MWL for short. It is a service, that dcm4chee server can provide and the modality (imaging equipment) has to be setup to query the service for worklist entries.

However there is another side to it - getting the orders in to dcm4chee. This is usually done by sending HL7 order messages from a HIS or RIS to dcm4chee. I don't see a way to manually input worklist entries into dcm4chee. This would also not be a very useful feature, since it would just shift the manual typing work from the modality to dcm4chee administration panel. In the HIS/RIS there should usually be all the relevant information already available and it's just a matter of configuring the HL7 messages to sent. (If Your HIS/RIS does support HL7 messaging. Could be, that it doesn't have support for that, if it has not been needed before and is a custom built in-house system or something)

So in short - You need to get orders in HL7 format into dcm4chee and then they will be available in worklist to be queried by a modality. The HL7 part might actually be the more difficult part.

Comment: Thanks Tarmo. I came to the same conclusion. I will use HL7 message to fill in the Modality Work List.